# Add up the floor function of a list of radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let [x] represent the greatest integer less than or equal to x. What is the value of 
[√5] + [√6] + [√7] + [√8] + [√9] + [√10] + [√11]?  The answer is 17

I added all the radicals up and come up with 19.6386….
Please help? What am I missing here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The proper notation is this:  $\lfloor x \rfloor$, read "floor of x."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is not true that $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor = \lfloor x + y \rfloor$ : for instance, take $x=y=1/2$.

So we don't have

$$\lfloor \sqrt{5} \rfloor+ \dotsb + \lfloor \sqrt{11} \rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{5}+\dotsb+\sqrt{11} \rfloor,
$$

and you need to compute the floor parts separately.

Answer (score 3):

[x] is an integer. You added up seven values of []. You should get an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\left\lfloor {\sqrt {n^{\,2} } } \right\rfloor  = \left| {\,n\,} \right|\quad \left| {\;{\rm integer}\,n} \right.
$$

and
$$
\left\lfloor {\sqrt k } \right\rfloor \quad \left| {\;n^{\,2} } \right. \le k < \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,2}  = n\quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integers}\,k,n} \right.
$$

So, you can group the calculation into
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\lfloor {\sqrt 5 } \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\sqrt 6 } \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\sqrt 7 } \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\sqrt 8 } \right\rfloor  = 2  \cr 
  & \left\lfloor {\sqrt 9 } \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\sqrt {10} } \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\sqrt {11} } \right\rfloor  = 3  \cr 
  & 8 + 9 = 17 \cr} 
$$